# How to debug/show all network requests in NativeScript?

Tags: nativescript, angular2-nativescript

How to debug/show all network requests in NativeScript in VisualCode?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not view / debug network requests with Visual Studio Code, simply it was not made for that. You are suppose to use the [Chrome dev tools](https://docs.nativescript.org/tooling/debugging/chrome-devtools#network).

Answer (score 1):

you simply write

`tns debug ios`

or

```
tns debug android
```